# Stop zsh incorporating /etc/hosts in autocomplete

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, hosts-file

I added loads of entries to my /etc/hosts file to aid in adblocking and tracking on the internet (a list I got from github https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts).

However, zsh now incorporates all the entries in the hosts file when searching for autocompletes. This means I can be moving a simple file with a long name and I type `mv w<TAB>` and I get hundreds of autocomplete entries with the filename I want buried in there somewhere.

Is there a way to restrict the sources zsh uses for autocompletion?

Edit: here are what I think are the relevant parts of my zshrc:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _ignored _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=1
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s
autoload -Uz compinit
autoload -U zutil
autoload -U complist
compinit
```

Comment: Let me guess... you are using d'oh-my-zsh or something similar?

Comment: @mpy Nope, no zsh plugins. I can post my .zshrc if it would help.

Comment: Yes, post your `.zshrc` if it's not too big. If it's more than 50 lines please try to narrow the behavior down to a specific part of it before.

Comment: @mpy Edited the question to include the relevant bits.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior when starting with `zsh -f` and the commands you included into your question? With zsh 5.2 I have no problems. Perhaps you should indeed include your whole config.

Comment: @mpy `zsh -f` solves the issue. I've also noticed that it only seems to happen with network related commands, for example ssh, scp, ftp etc. It doesn't actually happen with `mv` as it says in the original question.

Comment: Ok, then that's the feature, not a bug! `ssh` and so on expects a hostname and zsh gathers those e.g. from `/etc/hosts` or `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: @mpy Thanks for your help, maybe I'll open another question asking how to change the behaviour of this zsh feature so that it doesn't scan my hosts file.

Comment: Check out http://nion.modprobe.de/blog/archives/521-hostname-completion-with-zsh.html for a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

By default, zsh populates its `hosts` completion list [from the command `getent hosts`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/3d7215cc8277b39cd1e24ce5a04376d45bfbabf0/Completion/Unix/Type/_hosts#L22) if it's available, or from certain files, [including `/ect/hosts`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/3d7215cc8277b39cd1e24ce5a04376d45bfbabf0/Completion/Unix/Type/_hosts#L24).

If we want to [skip this part](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/3d7215cc8277b39cd1e24ce5a04376d45bfbabf0/Completion/Unix/Type/_hosts#L7), we need to provide our own completion logic. You can do so by adding the following to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
zstyle -e ':completion:*:hosts' hosts 'reply=(
  ${=${${(f)"$(cat {/etc/ssh_,~/.ssh/known_}hosts(|2)(N) 2>/dev/null)"}%%[#| ]*}//,/ }
  ${=${${${${(@M)${(f)"$(cat ~/.ssh/config 2>/dev/null)"}:#Host *}#Host }:#*\**}:#*\?*}}
)'
```

Inspiration: [Voku's solution in their dotfiles](https://github.com/voku/dotfiles/blob/master/.redpill/lib/4_completion.zsh#L83), by leaving out the `/ect/hosts` part.